# Configuring MVC for SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, connection-string, simplemembership

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a number of membership-related pages generated from the project templates.

When I attempt to access one of those pages, I get the following error:

> The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588.

After some time spent researching, I determined I was missing the connection string. I have an existing connection string named `FreeWebFilesEntities` and I created a new connection string named `DefaultConnection`, and gave it the same value.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FreeWebFilesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FreeWebFilesRepository.csdl|res://*/FreeWebFilesRepository.ssdl|res://*/FreeWebFilesRepository.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=FreeWebFiles;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FreeWebFilesRepository.csdl|res://*/FreeWebFilesRepository.ssdl|res://*/FreeWebFilesRepository.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=FreeWebFiles;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<connectionStrings>
```

But it still doesn't like this. I found some resources that suggested I'm using an EF connection string (and I am). I tried removing the metadata section of it but, no matter what I do, it throws an exception.

Since it appears Microsoft decided not to document this process very carefully (if at all), has anyone figured this out? How can I get the SimpleMembership pages to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, you are using a `EntityClient` connection string, which is incompatible with `SimpleMembership`.  `SimpleMembership` requires a `SqlClient` provider type connection string (ie, it does not have the metadata and the provider type is `SqlClient`)

Second, the connection string that is used is set in your `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` class, in particular the line that calls `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`.  You can change this to whatever you want.  DefaultConnection is the default connection string supplied in the machine.config, and does not by default show up in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But the connection strings have always been a bit of a mystery to me. I tried editing the connection string in several ways, as I described. But I still don't get what it needs in order to work. (Also, I know that the `DefaultConnection` connection string doesn't show up automatically. That's why I added it.)

Comment: @JonathanWood - you misunderstand.  Web.config files are hierarchical and machine.config is at the very bottom of that, and it contains the DefaultConnection.  You only need to override this if you want to name your connectionstring "DefaultConnection" but do not want to use the DefaultConnection as defined in machine.config.  If you don't want to name your connectionstring DefaultConnection, then you need to change the connection string name in the InitializeDatabaseConnection call in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs.

Comment: @JonathanWood - EntityClient connection strings include the metatdata that points to your .edmx file, SqlClient connection strings do not include that information.  SimpleMembershipProvider does not understand EntityClient connection strings, so you cannot use the same connection string as your EntityFramework classes with SimpleMembership.  If this is a "mystery" to you, you should do some research, because this is an important distinction to understand and not something you can continue to be ignorant of.

Comment: Thanks, but the name of the connection string is not where I'm having trouble. With each edit I make, I get a different exception. But I seem to be making progress. I would like to learn about this but there seems to be a lack of good information. And the information on using SimpleMembership is downright pathetic.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have these sections in your web.config file?

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: SimpleMembership does not use any config file entries for membership

Comment: Then you're saying that those sections should be pulled out of a working, code first, migrating, mvc project that uses SimpleMembership? Although, your right about the provider name needing to be System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "migrating" project, but SimpleMembership is configured in code via the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method, and does not use any config files for this.  To prove this to yourself, generate a new Internet MVC4 application, you will notice there are no membership entries in the config.

Comment: By 'migrating' I was referring to a dev project that uses DbMigration. I tip my hat to you with the fact that the SimpleMembership is initialized with the InitializeDatabaseConnection which create the sections in the web.config file.

Comment: To be clear, InitializeDatabaseConnection does not create anything in the web.config, but it does initialize the Membership.Provider dynamically in code, so the web.config entries are not needed (and in fact, are overridden by the InitializedDatabaseConnection method).  You can read the source for the WebSecurity class here http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/ConfigUtil.cs

Comment: Ok, you can stop pulling your hair out. I did as you suggested and created an new mvc test project and checked to see that the filter folder was created and the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs file was there. There were no membership section in the web.config file. Builded and ran it and registered a new user, logged out and closed it. There was still not membership section in the web.config file.